# NAudio get Left and Right speaker levels?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I'm currently fetching the master level fine with this:

```
MMDeviceEnumerator devEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
MMDevice defaultDevice = devEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
Console.WriteLine("Sending Volume level through " + port.PortName);
Console.WriteLine("\rCurrent Level: " + defaultDevice.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue.ToString());
```

But is it possible to get the Left and Right levels from all sound passing through?

I've looked around and have not found anything on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, Found out its:

defaultDevice.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues[0] // left
defaultDevice.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues[1] // right

Answer (score 2):

Correct! The Code Given Below Helped Me!

***VB.NET:-***

```vb
Dim MDE As New MMDeviceEnumerator
Dim MD As MMDevice = MDE.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia)
Dim CurrentSession = MD.AudioSessionManager.AudioSessionControl  REM Or Simply MD.AudioMeterInformation

ProgressBar1.Value = CurrentSession.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues(0) * 100 REM Left
ProgressBar2.Value = CurrentSession.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues(1) * 100 REM Right
```

***VCSharp (C#):-***

```cs
MMDeviceEnumerator MDE = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
MMDevice MD = MDE.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
var CurrentSession = MD.AudioSessionManager.AudioSessionControl; // Or Simply MD.AudioMeterInformation

progressBar1.Value = CurrentSession.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues[0] * 100; // Left
progressBar2.Value = CurrentSession.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues[1] * 100; // Right
```

Such A Helpful DLL (NAudio)

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I don't think this is the correct answer for balance.

Should be the following:

```
defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Channels[0]  // left
defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Channels[1]  // right
```